# Conflict between minted, colortbl and multicolumn (insertion of code in array cells)

Tags: tables, multicolumn, minted, colortbl

I am doing a table, where some cells contain code. I also want to color some cells. It is perfectly allowed to use minted inline code inside table cells. However, I can't use minted code in a multicolumn command. Here is a minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\mintinline{rust}|let r = &mut a[1];|} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I obtain the following error message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./minted-tabular.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty)
(./minted-tabular.w18))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))/usr/bin/pygmentize

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./minted-tabular.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
Runaway argument?
let r = 
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \minted@inline@ii.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9 ...{l|}{\mintinline{rust}|let r = &mut a[1];|}
                                                   \\
?
```

Note that this is a conflict between *three* libraries. If I don't include `colortbl` this file compile. Also, I still can use minted inline in array cells.

What is happening? what can I do?

Comment: You are right, the previous code compiled just right. I analysed my original code again and I found that my compilation error comes from a conflict with the colortbl library. I edited my minimal example and the title of the issue.

Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another pair of braces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{{\mintinline{rust}|let r = &mut a[1];|}} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The error you get is due to `\mintinline` doing further forward scan, and this somehow conflicts with `colortbl` refactoring of table cell templates.